# Does Intuit provide developers access to add weekly Timesheets into Quick books online account

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I have succeeded in adding single Time Activity from my .net application into my quickbooks account, but we have a requirement to add weekly timesheets for the employess into Qbs.

Does Intuit provide access to add weekly timesheets into quick books online account using IPP Devkit 2.0 ??

Thanks in Advance
Deepthi

Comment: You have to add individual entries to make up the week. There is not a single weekly command.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add individual entries to make up the week. There is not a single weekly command. 
Per William